# Qt Creator: how to hide members?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4

I've created a form in Qt Creator 4 and 'compile' it to python module with pyuic4. Everything is ok but when I call the class represented my for it contains over 20 form elements as a *public* members (including Spacers etc.). But I need only 5 of them. It's not fatal but annoying... Is there a way to declare an element in Qt Creator as private/hidden? I mean it has to be done in Qt Creator because if I'll make any changes and recompile .ui file all changes in .py file would be overwritten.

Comment: Python doesn't have private members, everything is public.  Can you provide an example of the exact problem you're having?

Comment: _single_leading_underscore: weak "internal use" indicator.

Comment: > Python doesn't have private members -- wow. o_O Never can imagine something like that...

Answer (score 0):

The pyuic tool uses the `objectName` to generate the names of the top-level class and its members. So to make a member "private", just prepend some underscores to the `objectName` property in the designer component.